# Interpret forecast output - standard error?

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

I ran the function forecast to get predicted values from a seasonal arima model. Please see the picture.
[image: Output]

What are the values in the left column? I guess they are the standard error? How are the prediction intervals obtained? I tried 28.67188+1.96*3.343600, but I dont get 22.9292106. 
The values in left column rise with time, thats why assumed they are the standard error, as the prediction intervals get wider with time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
As I used frequency=365.25 and my time series had 856 daily observations, it calculated that the ts is from 1 until 3.34 years (=856/365.25+1).

Therefore, the left column indicates the next time value.